# Preloading local image assets in Flutter

Tags: dart, flutter

I have a list of image assets, and I have one Image widget onscreen. I use a button to cycle through them, using setState().

```dart
    const List<String> _photoData = const [
      "assets/generic-cover.jpg",
      "assets/generic-cover2.jpg",
      "assets/generic-cover3.jpg",
      "assets/generic-cover4.jpg",
    ];

    class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {

      int _coverPhoto = 0;

      void _switchCoverPhoto() {
        setState(() {
          _coverPhoto++;
          if (_coverPhoto == _photoData.length) {
             _coverPhoto = 0;
          }
        });
      }

      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {

        return new Scaffold(
          body: new Stack(
            children: <Widget>[
              new Image.asset (
                _photoData[_coverPhoto],
                fit: ImageFit.cover,
                height: 600.0,
              ),
              new Positioned ( // photo toggle button
                child: new IconButton(
                  icon: new Icon (Icons.photo),
                  onPressed: _switchCoverPhoto,
                  color: Colors.white,
                ),
                top: 32.0,
                right: 32.0,
              ),
            ]
          )
        );
      }
```

The first image renders fine. However, when I call _switchCoverPhoto(), there's a brief white flash before "assets/generic-cover2.jpg" gets shown.

Which leads to a simple question: Is there an easy way to preload a subsequent image (or images) into memory, so that there's no flash beforehand?

[See attached GIF for a loose approximation.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z4ZMD.gif)

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Make sure you have `gaplessPlayback` set to `true` for your image.

This won't solve the preloading problem, but it will prevent the image from flashing to white when switching assets.

With gaplessPlayback set to true, your original image will remain until the new image has completed loading and no "white flash gap" will be present.

```
var img = new Image.asset(
  _photoData[_coverPhoto],
  fit: ImageFit.cover,
  height: 600.0,
  gaplessPlayback: true,
);
```

Comment: may God bless your soul bro. It freaking worked!!!